# PHP rich text editor initializable with html

Tags: php, html, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

Hi i need rich text editor for my website that can take my html file as a input in start. Could someone reccomend me that kind of a free php competible rich text editor that i can initialize with my precreated html and i need get output from it(word or excel or pdf etc.)

Comment: Compare `TinyMCE ` with `ckEditor`. They are both widely used. I use ckEditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TinyMCE` text editor

```
<?php
 $allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img>';
 $allowedTags.='<li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del>';  
// Should use some proper HTML filtering here.
  if($_POST['elm1']!='') {
    $sHeader = '<h1>Ah, content is king.</h1>';
    $sContent = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['elm1']),$allowedTags);
} else {
    $sHeader = '<h1>Nothing submitted yet</h1>';
    $sContent = '<p>Start typing...</p>';
    $sContent.= '<p><img width="107" height="108" border="0" src="/mediawiki/images/badge.png"';
    $sContent.= 'alt="TinyMCE button"/>This rover has crossed over</p>';
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>My test editor - with tinyMCE and PHP</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode: "exact",
    elements : "elm1",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,"
    + "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,"
    + "bullist,numlist,outdent,indent",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "link,unlink,anchor,image,separator,"
    +"undo,redo,cleanup,code,separator,sub,sup,charmap",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    height:"350px",
    width:"600px"
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo $sHeader;?>
 <h2>Sample using TinyMCE and PHP</h2>
 <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>">
  <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80"><?php echo $sContent;?></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Download editor](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php)

Comment: it should good for me but elm1 is not defined?

Comment: sorry plz use isset($_POST['elm1']) @Furkan

Comment: Can i get msword output with using button on editor?

Comment: or should i use additional different library for html to msword?

Comment: you need additional library .it will give you html responses

Comment: Does this have print function in it? @Rahautos

Comment: plz check this link http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:print

Comment: tinymce.init({
    plugins: "print",
    toolbar: "print"
});

Comment: add these code   @Furkan